# Cannot GET / Node.js when publish with azure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, azure, loopback

i just have a problem when i publish to azure . it said: Cannot GET / when i open the website .

i using static site with node.js , angular.js, and loopback(API)

here my client side (site.js):

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Public'));

var server = app.listen(1338, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

There is index.html inside Public Folder .

this is my Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "angular-site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "static server to server Node.js",
  "main": "site.js",
  "author": "Jordan Leonardi",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.8.5"
  }
}
```

when i tried to localhost, its look Fine, but when i tried to Azurewebsites its give me back an error " Cannot GET / " . .

Comment: Are you capturing `.get`? Such as `app.get('/', (req, res) => {});`

Comment: As other answers mention (such as the one I marked as a duplicate of), Web Apps cannot listen on anything but port 80 and 443 (from outside), and you must get the correct port from the environment. You cannot simply listen on port 1338.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, you should use `process.env.PORT || 1338` instead of custom port `1338` when you deploy your app to cloud service such as Azure App Service, Heroku etc.

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't seem to have setup a route for `/`.
Your current implementation will return only the files in the `/Public` directory, when asked for. But the root route is not assigned.

You can use:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World'));
```

Comment: so if i have index.html in /Public directory , it will like this?

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) {
  res.send('index.html')
})

Comment: @j.lo your index page will launch automatically, your server needs to be able to interpret the request for `mywebsite.com`, in your case will be `/`. You can handle that with the code provided by tbking.

Comment: as @JayGould said, whatever is there in the `/Public` directory will be handled automatically. But what's not there has to be handled by code like this. In this case, it's the landing page of your website. so `mywebsite.com/` has that `/` in the end, that's the path you need to handle with this code.